# Gallery overlapping items click

Tags: android, click, gallery, overlapping

I have a Gallery based View with a negative spacing between elements, so that one zoomed out behind the previous, i.e. 'carousel'. Zooming and carousel effect is achieved by Camera transformation.

The problem arises when I try to click right side of foreground item and what I really get is click on item behind it (always to right of it)

Let me enumerate what I've already tried:

1. setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
2. z coordinate of background item is obviously greater then foreground
   one
3. getChildDrawingOrder was overridden as many ways as possible (and I
   found out that it doesn't play any role at all - touch events don't
   depend on visibility order of views)

Seems like next(right) child has greater index and therefore a priority of handling UI events, and my z-coordinate/drawing order manipulations don't change anything.

So question: how to make foreground item responsible for all click events on it?

Comment: any solution u could share?